# Submenu doesn´t show/hide on my ng-click($index)

Tags: angularjs, menu, submenu

I'm trying to do a tree menu on my site. 
I want the subitems to show/hide when I click the parent. 
This solution don't work. Even tho it changes the `item.active` value to false/true. Any ides my friends?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
<div class="cssTreeMenu tree">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
         <li ng-repeat="item in items" >
            <a ui-sref="{{item.sref}}" ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="testcolaps($index)">{{item.name}}</a>              
            <ul ng-show="{{item.active}}" class="navbarColorOnClick">
                <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems" ui-sref-active="active">
                    <a ui-sref="{{subItem.sref}}">{{subItem.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
 $scope.testcolaps = function (index) {
    $scope.items[index].active = !$scope.items[index].active;     
};

$scope.items = [
    {
        name: "Test",
        sref: "kpi.test",
        active: false,
        subItems: [
            {
                name: "Selectable KPI menu",
                sref: "kpi.selectableKpiMenu"
            },
            {
                name: "Test",
                sref: "kpi.test"
            }
        ]
    },
     {
         name: "Test2",
         sref: "kpi.test",
         active: false,
         subItems: [
             {
                 name: "Selectable KPI menu 2",
                 sref: "kpi"
             },
             {
                 name: "Test 2",
                 sref: "internal"
             }
         ]
     },
];
```

As you can se my items have a `active:` property who I change to true/false. But still nothing happens in my menu. If I hard-code it to true it is showing like it should but still the click-event doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression inside the `ng-show` need an expression without `{{}}` interpolation. Basically you need to remove `{{}}`.

```
ng-show="item.active"
```

Comment: OMG I'm a retard hahaha! Thank you. Now it works like a charm! i feel so stupid! Thanks man!